# Javascript word counter

Tags: javascript, counter, cpu-word

I wanted to make a basic word counter based on the amount of whitespaces in a sentence, but for some reason it doesn't work.

```js
function countWords(str) {
  if (typeof str == "string" && str.length > 0) {
    var counter = 1;
    for (var i; i < str.length; i++) {
      if (str[i] === " ") {
        counter += 1;
      }
    }
    return counter;
  } else {
    throw Error("You must input a string.");
  }
}

console.log(countWords("hello World"));
```

This throws 1 instead of 2.

Comment: Why is `var` not initialized to 0?

Comment: I would convert the string into an array with `str.split(' ')`. This will split the sentence at each space, and return an array with each word in it, and then you can count the length of the array to find out how many words there are: `console.log(str.split(' ').length);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize `i` to zero.

Replace `for (var i;` with `for (var i=0;`

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a loop for this. You would rather just split the string by space and take the resulting array's length

```js
let countWords = str => str.split(' ').length;
console.log(countWords("foo bar"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You must initilize the counter inside the for, like `var i = 0;` here is your code

```
function countWords(str) {
if (typeof str=="string" && str.length>0) {
var counter=1;
for (var i;i<str.length;i++) {
    if (str[i]===" ") {
        counter+=1;
    }
}
return counter;
}
else {
    throw Error("You must input a string.");
}
}

countWords("hello World");
```

Or you can count words with `str.split(" ").length`

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop was wrong

```js
function countWords(str) {
if (typeof str=="string" && str.length>0) {
    var counter=1;
    for (var i = 0;i<str.length;i++) {
        if (str[i]===" ") {
            counter+=1;
        }
    }
return counter;
}
else {
    throw Error("You must input a string.");
}
}

var str = "hello World this is me";
console.log(countWords(str));
```